# Can i publish a game with famous character heroes?

Tags: copyright, conceptualization, character

I am working on a iOS game where a player has to hit multiple balloons with a superhero.

Can I use cartoon images such as this one from the video without getting issued for copyright?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nL-j3n2NU7k

An artist will draw the heroes from scratch.

Comment: In the US anyone can sue anyone for anything. The fact that you need to ask this question kind of indicates you *already know* the answer to it and are *hoping* someone tells you it's okay.

Comment: If you live in a country with no copyright law go for it. You can't do this in America or any country that uses copyright

Answer (score 3):

First of all: Deadpool is a Marvel character. It's their character, their story and they are building this up as a business for a very long time. I'm quite sure they will get very angry if you use the name or even just a very similar character, especially with a product like a game. Even if it is non-commercial. Only if you modify the look and the name this could work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot legally publish it without having a written and signed permission to use the characters. If you use drawings of other artists, you need in additon permissions for all of them.

If you have already made the game but haven't all needed permissions, you are in safe if you do not give your work to anyone, sell it nor put it available for free.

Who can give a permission? Only the copyright owner, it's your job to find them. Unknown owner does give no rights to you. Well known famous characters usually belong to established publishers and it's easy to find how to get the needed permissions. Probably you must pay for every copy.

NOTE: The local law affects, too. What I wrote is generally true in developed western countries.

Answer (score 1):

If going commercial with the game:

1. make sure your artist and all external providers transfer all copyright for their work to you or the entity publishing the game. you need to own every asset used in the final product (the game).
2. avoid replicating any existing artwork and commission an artist which can create original work. sure, there's always inspiration, but no need to actually copy existing work on purpose.